# reset jquery slider

Tags: jquery-ui-slider

How can I reset jquery slider so it as set default values as calls all callback methods like slide etc?

```
$('#value-slider').slider({
    min: 1000,
    max: 20000000,
    values: [ 1, 20000000 ],
    step: 1000,
    range: true,
    slide: function(event,ui){
        $('#search-panel input[name="value1"]').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#search-panel input[name="value2"]').val(ui.values[1]);
        $('#value-count span').text(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1] );
    }
});
```

Comment: only that person that made the script can tell you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no built in function reset, had to write own reset

Comment: Nice one, accepted with -1 ! :p Sucks if there is no reset method :/

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the following snippet

$("#value-slider").slider("value", $("#value-slider").slider("option", "min") );