# How to reset slider in the <div>?/ How to clear elements in <div>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html

I want to reset the `<div id="slider">` on clicking certain button.

`<div>` contains the slider (not important here).

is there any function like `$(#slider).reset()` or `$(#slider).clear()` or anything that clears the slider `<div>`?

Comment: it would be helpful if u put some sample code.

Comment: what is exactly meant by "clears the slider"?

Comment: Are you using jQuery ui or something?

Comment: clears slider mean reset to a certain position

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127604/reset-jquery-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a value, e.g. the minimum for this slider (`0`):

```
$('#slider').slider("value", 0);
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JSKvD/).

To set to the maximum:

```
$('#slider').slider('value', $("#slider").slider("option", "max"));
```

Also see my [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/JSKvD/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

I've updated [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/JSKvD/12/) once more. Now you can alert the current value and set the maximum to 30 too:

```
$('#slider').slider('option', 'max', 30);
...
alert($('#slider').slider('value'));
```

Comment: I want to set max value dynamically   so I tried $("#slider").slider("max",30);  which doesn't seem working

Comment: Does not work on range slider: Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance

Answer (score 2):

to reset the slider

```
   $("#value-slider").slider("value", $("#value-slider").slider("option", "min") );
```

to empty a div

```
$("#value-slider").empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to judge what exactly you want, but have a look at this :

[reset jquery slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127604/reset-jquery-slider)

[How to reset a jQuery UI slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331728/jquery-slider-reset)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slider-moving-slider-back-to-beginning-slider-reset-method

Example :

```
$("#slider").slider("value", $("#slider").slider("option", "min") );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `empty()` which can suffice your need. 
You can try

```
$("#slider").empty()
```

This will clear your `<div>` so that you can reset some other slider on it again

Comment: kindly go through documentation http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider      it's always often best way to follow the docs

Comment: Scessor answered it right... do it as $("#slider").slider("option", max,30);  neglecting "option" will not work... however it will work for "value" and "values" even if you neglect "option"..

Answer (score 0):

http://slidesjs.com/

Sliderjs:

To reset to first slide, 
Apply the following line in cancel or close button click event
$('.pagination li:first a').click();

http://letslearn-kannan.blogspot.in/